# Magento 2.3.4 - Order don't get Recorded in Admin

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, onepage-checkout

**1** `Magento 2.3.4`

**2** `PHP 7.3`

**3** `Braintree Gene 4.0.4`

**4** `Default Onepage Checkout`

---

Is there a magento developer who can help me? We have newly upgraded to magento 2 website. I am facing issues with order and payments. Which I never faced in M1

With the below order number, the order never got recorded in magento nor I received a confirmation email. But braintree deducted the payment.

`1000002100`

With the below order numbers, the `amount,details and sku` are same. Braintree processed this as three separate orders and deducted the payment thrice.

`1000002094`, `1000002095`, `1000002096`

The order increment is getting skipped. Please check the screenshot, and further details can be provided.

**Screenshot**

https://prnt.sc/u0oxz6

This is a serious issue, still pending in **Magento 2**. Please look into the matter, and suggest what can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much for your reply Sumit in my case (Stores > Configuration > Customers > Persistent Shopping Cart) is disable

Answer (score 0):

1. The increment id is assigned on the customer quote as column name **reserved_order_id**,
2. The working flow of placing order.

- Client click place order
- Magento reserved an order increment id by using **sequence_order** table
- Update the newest record into the current quote.
- Place the order and save the order if the process is succeeded.
- If not throw an error and keep the reserved order id at the quote.
- At the next time will use the reserved id to place order again ignore getting  newest increment id

Sometime you will see the order's increment id is not ordered.

Comment: Thanks very much your views. Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @gilbertsohal, basically that is the best way to make sure the order increment isn't duplicated.

Comment: Yeah thanks! But in my case Braintree taking payments and order don't get recorded in magento admin.

Comment: @gilbertsohal, because the transaction isn't completed, the order shouldn't save on the admin.

Comment: The problem is we are getting money and order is not showing in admin so we don't know the order details some time braintree showing 3 - 4 payments with same price..